# vb.net browse for folder description space is not enough

Tags: vb.net, folderbrowserdialog

I am using the `FolderBrowserDialog` to allow the user to choose a folder where to store files. I am also using the `description` property to give the user tips as to where to ideally place such a folder. However, the space for the description text only seems to allow 3 lines of text which is not enough for me. The rest of the text is getting truncated. Is there a way to force the dialog box to allow for longer descriptions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**FolderBrowserDialog** is a sealed class. You can't derive a new class from it.
If you wanto to enlarge the Description label to accomodate for more than three lines, you need to use SubClassing methods which involve PInvoke and a lot of API Calls. This will become quickly really complex.

For what it's worth, I suggest you try to shorten the description.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like the most feasible option at the moment.